# Anular test and build with Azure devops TFS issue while chrome-headless

Tags: azure-devops

I can use and install chrome-headless with puppeteer in azure devops by (dev.azure) but its not working in azure devops TFS.
Shows error that "chromium install is failed"

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: its found that build agent used for the TFS not allowing to download chromium from other domains due to proxy so waiting on the agent to get prepared

Answer (score 0):

For this issue , if the task you installed is **[VSTS Chromium Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=schlumberger.chromium-build-tasks-Preview)**, then this task should not be applicable in TFS.

[image]

As stated in the task description: This task automates the Process of Installing Chromium on your **Hosted Build Agent** in VSTS so that you can run your javascript tests with a headless browser.

However, there is no hosted agent in TFS, only self-hosted agent. So chromium installation will fail . At present, chromium can only installed in azure devops service.